# How to serialize a lazy fetched hibernate field as reference?

Tags: hibernate, jackson, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

Using Jackson with Hibernate, I have some lazy fetched fields. I want them to be represented by its id (similar to the effect of @JsonIdentityReference), not embedding the whole object or as null.

However, I could only achieve the following effect:

1. With Jackson-datatype-hibernate, lazy fetched fields are serialized as null, while I need reference.
2. With @JsonIdentityReference, and change the fetchType to eager, I got the field serialized as id (reference). However, the field is eagerly fetched, which a drawback for the performance.

I would like to have solution that has the advantage of the above two cases: The field is lazy fetched, so no need to query the database unless needed. An id reference is contained in the generated Json object, so that the client could issue a seperate query to get the entity with the reference.

My intention is similar to what spring data rest does: entities within the same aggregate root is embedded in the aggregate root. Relations to other aggregate root are represented as links.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this feature of `HibernateModule` in addition with `FORCE_LAZY_LOADING` to false?:

```
hibernateModule.configure(Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false); 
hibernateModule.configure(Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS, true);
```

The ouput on a not initialized proxy looks like:

```
{
    "somefield" : "value",
    "link": {
        "id" = idValue
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to [customize the Jackson Object Mapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) and register in an [Hibernate module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) with the above configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extend `Hibernate5Module`(`Hibernate4Module`) and add that `id` yourself.
To get the `id` from a proxy

```
public static Serializable getId(Object persistent) {
    if (!(persistent instanceof HibernateProxy)) {
        return null;
    }

    LazyInitializer initializer = ((HibernateProxy) persistent)
        .getHibernateLazyInitializer();

    return initializer.getIdentifier();
}
```